# Why is the /questions URL labelled different than all other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, title

I have a bookmark that goes to the /question URL of a bunch of sites I monitor.  I notice that the Title in the browser for all of them is Newest questions.  But on Sci Fi-SE it is Recently Active questions.

Is there any meaning/matter to this distinction, or is it purely cosmetic?  Fun to be different, regardless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are five tabs underneath /questions, specified with an optional argument appended to the URL:

- [newest](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)
- [frequent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent)
- [votes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes)
- [active](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active)
- [unanswered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered)

If you have [/questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions) bookmarked (without the argument), the next time you visit the site you'll re-open the tab that you visited most recently (I imagine SE sets a cookie to store this information).

Presumably you're seeing something like this, with **active** underlined and bolded:

[image]

If you click on the **newest** link, it should remember your setting for next time:

[image]